# How to set login button go to next applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

How to set the button to go to next applet? The code is like:

```
if (strp.matches(strp) && stru.matches(stru)) {
    register rg=new register();
    rg.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User name or password are not correct.");
    return;
}
```

After confirming the password and username, it only shows blank. How to set the applet so that after clicking button it will go to next applet?

Comment: In brief, the 'applets' should be panels. Use a `CardLayout` for flipping between the views.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below...

```
if (strp.matches(strp) && stru.matches(stru))
{
    Class applet2 = Class.forName("register"); // give complete name of register class including package name
    Applet appletToLoad = (Applet)applet2.newInstance();
    appletToLoad.setStub(this);
    setLayout( new GridLayout(1,0));
    add(appletToLoad);
    appletToLoad.init();
    appletToLoad.start();
}
else
{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User name or password are not correct.");
     return;
}
```